# jQuery clearTimeout on ajax success is getting confused and not clearing previous timeouts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have a form submitted by jQuery ajax which has error validation server side. On beforeSend I show
a gif loader and some loading text and when validation is send back on success method I show the appropriate messages for error.
This messages have timeout to hide after x seconds. Anyways when i continue clicking the submit button,
setTimeout is confusing itself and previous ones are not clearing. Here is the code I am using:

**EDIT**

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
var timer = null;

$.ajax({
    beforeSend; function() {
        $('.response').html('Processing form, please wait...');
    },

    success: function(data) {

        if(data.error == true) {
            $('.response').html('An error occurred.');
        } else {
            $('.response').html('Thank you. Form submitted successfully.');
        }

        if(timer) { clearTimeout(timer) };
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $('.response').html('* Indicates required fields.');
        }, 10000); 

    }
});
});
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `timer` variable is scoped to your `success` function, so it's *always* `null` when your code to clear the old timeout is reached. Move the declaration of `timer` outside your AJAX call, and it should work.

```
var timer = null;

$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() { ... },
    success: function(data) {
        if(timer) { clearTimeout(timer) };
        timer = setTimeout(myfunction, 10000); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too, but still the same result.

Comment: @user558134 You'll have to give us more of the code if that doesn't work because without it, we don't have enough context to know what is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I posted some more code. That's pretty much it.

Comment: @user558134 That code should work perfectly fine. There have to be some sort of additional scoping issues that aren't apparent in the code you've posted.

Comment: It is working well now. Though in my case, I had to define the timer two levels up in my code outside the $(form).submit();